# Python crash coursebook alien invasion game

Tags: python-3.x

I encountered an error while trying to fire bullets in the alien invasion game I copied most of the code from the book but I must have left somethings out. This is my whole code and since I started to add the bullets i haven't been able to move the ship does anyone have a solution?

pythoncrashcoursebook.py

```
import pygame

import refactors as rf
from game_settings import Settings
from ship import Ship
from pygame.sprite import Group


def run_game():
    # Initialize game and make a screen object and caption
    pygame.init()
    # Make a settings instance
    settings = Settings()
    # Make a screen
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((settings.screen_height, settings.screen_width))
    # Make a ship
    ship = Ship(screen, settings)
    # Make a group to store bullets
    bullets = Group()
    # Display caption
    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

    # Main game loop
    while True:
        rf.check_events(settings, screen, ship, bullets)
        ship.update()
        bullets.update()

        rf.update_screen(settings, screen, ship, bullets)


run_game()
```

ship.py

```
import pygame


class Ship:
    def __init__(self, screen, settings):
        # Initialize the ship and start position
        self.screen = screen
        self.settings = settings

        # Load the image and get the rect of the ship
        self.image = pygame.image.load("spaceship.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

        # Set the ship at the bottom of the screen
        self.rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx
        self.rect.bottom = self.screen_rect.bottom

        # Store a decimal value for the ship's center
        self.center = float(self.rect.centerx)

        # Moving flag
        self.moving_right = False
        self.moving_left = False

    def update(self):
        if self.moving_right and self.rect.right < self.screen_rect.right:
            self.center += self.settings.ship_speed_factor
        if self.moving_left and self.rect.left > 0:
            self.center -= self.settings.ship_speed_factor

        # Update rect object from self.center
        self.rect.centerx = self.center

    def blitme(self):
        # Draw the ship
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

bullet.py

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite


class Bullet(Sprite):

"""Class to control bullet"""

def __init__(self, settings, screen, ship):
    """Create bullet at ship position"""
    super(Bullet, self).__init__()
    self.screen = screen

    # Create bullet rect at (0, 0) and then correct position
    self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, settings.bullet_width, settings.bullet_height)
    self.rect.centerx = ship.rect.centerx
    self.rect.top = ship.rect.top

    # Store the bullet's position as a decimal
    self.y = float(self.rect.y)

    # Store bullet colour and speed
    self.colour = settings.bullet_colour
    self.bullet_speed = settings.bullet_speed_factor

def update_bullet(self):
    """Move the bullet up the screen"""
    self.y -= self.bullet_speed

    # Update rect position
    self.rect.y = self.y

def draw_bullet(self):
    """Draw bullet on the screen"""
    pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.colour, self.rect)
```

game_settings.py

```
class Settings:
    # A class to store all the game settings
    def __init__(self):
        # Ship settings
        self.ship_speed_factor = 1.5

        # Screen settings
        self.bg_colour = (0, 0, 255)
        self.screen_height = 800
        self.screen_width = 600

        # Bullet settings
        self.bullet_colour = 60, 60, 60
        self.bullet_height = 15
        self.bullet_width = 3
        self.bullet_speed_factor = 1
```

refactors.py

```
import sys

import pygame

from bullet import Bullet


def check_events(ship, settings, screen, bullets):
    #  Check for events and assign functions to them
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        #  To quit
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            check_key_down_event(event, ship, settings, screen, bullets)
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            check_key_up_event(event, ship)


def check_key_down_event(event, ship, settings, screen, bullets):
    """Respond to keypress"""
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        ship.moving_right = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        ship.moving_left = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
        # Create a mew bullet and add it to the bullet group
        new_bullet = Bullet(settings, screen, ship)
        bullets.add(new_bullet)


def check_key_up_event(event, ship):
    """Respond to key releases"""
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        ship.moving_right = False
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        ship.moving_left = False


def update_screen(settings, screen, ship, bullets):
    screen.fill(settings.bg_colour)
    # Redraw all bullets behind aliens and ship
    for bullet in bullets.sprites():
        bullet.draw_bullet()

    ship.blitme()
    pygame.display.flip()
```

And this is the error

```
line 14, in __init__
    self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, settings.bullet_width, settings.bullet_height)
AttributeError: 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'bullet_width'
```

Answer (score -1):

You should try changing:

```
rf.check_events(settings, screen, ship, bullets)
```

to:

```
rf.check_events(ship, settings, screen, bullets)
```

in your main code.